# How to access API response message-id

Tags: mailgun

I can't find a way to access the API call response in order to collect the message-id of the email.

```
require_once('/root/vendor/autoload.php');

use Mailgun\Mailgun;

$mg = Mailgun::create('key-myprivatekey');

$mg->messages()->send('mail.mywebsite.com', [
  'from'    => 'Mywebsite <contact@mywebsite.com>',
  'to'      => 'hello@gmail.com',
  'subject' => 'The PHP SDK is awesome!',
  'text'    => 'It is so simple to send a message.',
  'o:tracking'=>'yes',
  'o:tracking-clicks'=>'yes',
  'o:tracking-opens'=>'yes'
]);


// echo message-id from $mg response
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$return = $mg->messages()->send($domain, $params);
    print_r($return);
```